cleveref treats all ntheorem environments as lemmas
I seem to be unable to get cleveref to reference results by their desired type. I am using ntheorem to create environments, making all subsequent environment types share the lemma counter. My problem is that they are then all referenced as lemmas.
A minimal working example is as follows:
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\geometry{letterpaper}   

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{extarrows}

\usepackage[colorlinks,
linkcolor=black!75!red,
citecolor=blue,
pdftitle={},
pdfproducer={pdfLaTeX},
pdfpagemode=None,
bookmarksopen=true,
bookmarksnumbered=true,
backref=page]{hyperref}


%%% Theorems and references %%%
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks,hyperref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\theoremstyle{plain}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}[lemma]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{theorem}[lemma]{Theorem}

\crefname{lemma}{lemma}{lemmas}
\crefformat{lemma}{#2lemma~#1#3} 
\Crefformat{lemma}{#2Lemma~#1#3} 

\crefname{theorem}{theorem}{theorems}
\crefformat{theorem}{#2theorem~#1#3} 
\Crefformat{theorem}{#2Theorem~#1#3}

\crefname{proposition}{proposition}{propositions}
\crefformat{proposition}{#2proposition~#1#3} 
\Crefformat{proposition}{#2Proposition~#1#3} 

%%%%%

\title{}

\begin{document}

\date{}


\maketitle

\begin{theorem}\label{th:boo}
\end{theorem}

\begin{proposition}\label{pr:boo}
\end{proposition}

\Cref{th:boo}

\Cref{pr:boo}

\Cref{th:boo,pr:boo}

\end{document}

This produces
Theorem 0.1 Statement.
Proposition 0.2 Statement.
Lemma 0.1
Lemma 0.2
Lemmas 0.1 and 0.2

As far as I can tell, I am at the time of this writing up to date with my TeX Live installation: I have it installed on a Linux system by following the TL instructions, and seeking further package updates with tlmgr produces
$ tlmgr update --self --all 
tlmgr: package repository https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
tlmgr: saving backups to /home/chirvasitua/texlive/2024/tlpkg/backups
tlmgr: no self-updates for tlmgr available
tlmgr: no updates available

Additional info:
This is new behavior; I type much TeX, and am positive this code was working fine just days ago. I am guessing some upgrade to one of the three main packages involved (ntheorem, cleveref, hyperref) broke something.
Also, this does not seem to be an issue of mis-ordering packages.

You can find a patch at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/730164/4427, but only for amsthm. Are you really bound to ntheorem?

cleveref patches lots of internals but hasn't been updated sind 2018 and so didn't follow development in the LaTeX kernel.
You can reinstate the behaviour by declaring the alias explicitly with LaTeX hooks:
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\geometry{letterpaper}   

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{extarrows}

\usepackage[colorlinks,
linkcolor=black!75!red,
citecolor=blue,
pdftitle={},
pdfproducer={pdfLaTeX},
pdfpagemode=None,
bookmarksopen=true,
bookmarksnumbered=true,
backref=page]{hyperref}


%%% Theorems and references %%%
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{cleveref}
  
\theoremstyle{plain}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}[lemma]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{theorem}[lemma]{Theorem}

% declare alias for cleveref
\AddToHook{env/proposition/begin}{\crefalias{lemma}{proposition}}
\AddToHook{env/theorem/begin}{\crefalias{lemma}{theorem}}


\crefname{lemma}{lemma}{lemmas}
\crefformat{lemma}{#2lemma~#1#3} 
\Crefformat{lemma}{#2Lemma~#1#3} 

\crefname{theorem}{theorem}{theorems}
\crefformat{theorem}{#2theorem~#1#3} 
\Crefformat{theorem}{#2Theorem~#1#3}

\crefname{proposition}{proposition}{propositions}
\crefformat{proposition}{#2proposition~#1#3} 
\Crefformat{proposition}{#2Proposition~#1#3} 

%%%%%

\title{}

\begin{document}

\date{}


\maketitle

\begin{theorem}\label{th:boo}
\end{theorem}

\begin{proposition}\label{pr:boo}
\end{proposition}

\Cref{th:boo}

\Cref{pr:boo}

\Cref{th:boo,pr:boo}

\end{document}



Thank you! Yes, this worked for me in the same fashion. It'll be a bit of a pain to go back and patch who knows how many files (especially since the problem is "silent" unless you actually spot a faulty reference), but it'll have to do.

yes, sorry but I don't have the time currently to figure out how to reinstate the cleveref patch. Write the maintainer and ask that he updates the package.

Of late, Toby Cubitt appears to have become more interested in the Chaitin Phase Transition problem and, more broadly, in Undecidability in Physics.
